# Чем вызвана такая ошибка компиляции при использовании объекта класса, содержащего и используещего мьютекс из STL (C++11)?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, visual-c++, c++11

> error C2280: 'std::mutex &std::mutex::operator =(const std::mutex &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

Определение класса с мьютексом внутри

```
    class ClassName
    {
    private:
        ...
        /// Multi-Threaded "guard" object.
        mutable std::mutex mt_guard_;
        ...
```

Код класса компилится нормально. Ошибка возникает при компиляции файла с `main()`, где идёт создание и использование данного класса.

Компилятор - MSVS 2013.

Всем спасибо, кто подскажет причину...

Comment: Ну так покажите, как создается  и используется объект этого класса.

Comment: Вероятно, Вы где-то присваиваете переменные типа `ClassName` друг другу. При этом работает копирующий конструктор по умолчанию, который пытается присвоить одной переменной типа `std::mutex` другую. Мьютексы присваивать друг другу нельзя, поэтому и возникает ошибка компиляции.

Comment: kff, спасибо. верно подсказали... =)

Comment: Да, проблема была с operator = () по-умолчанию, нельзя присваивать друг другу мьютексы. При написании своего operator = () всё лечится.

Comment: @kff Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение об ошибке довольно ясное: мьютексы не являются копируемыми объектами. Конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания для этого класса объявлены как удаленные

```
mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
mutex& operator=(const mutex&) = delete;
```

Поэтому вы не можете их явно или неявно использовать.

Относительно вашей программы компилятор сообщает, что вы где-то в коде пытаетесь тем не менее присвоить один объект вашего класса другому объекту этого же класса, что приводит к попытке вызова копирующего оператора присваивания для мьютекса. В результате генерируется сообщение об ошибке.